# Jquery switch class on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the folowing example:

```
<div class="filtrer">
    <a class="bold">Url 1</a>
    <a>Url 2</a>
</div>
```

First url is active, second is inactive, bold means is selected. I should be allowed to press only on Url 2, and as soon as i do that, the bold class shoud switch to the Url 2.

What i already tryed and did not work was this:

```
$('.filtrer a').filter(':not(.bold)').on('click', function(){
    var current = $('.filtrer a').filter(':not(.bold)');
    var standby = $('.filtrer a.bold');

    current.addClass('bold');
    standby.removeClass('bold');
})
```

Does anybody know why this is not working? Or have an optimized solution? Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you change $('.filtrer a') to $('.filter a')?

Comment: Sory, i corrected that spelling mistake.

Comment: What about the single quote / double quote on your bold anchor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are dealing with dynamic element selectors, so you need to use delegation based event handlers

```
var $as = $('.filter a');
$('.filter').on('click', 'a:not(.bold)', function () {
    var current = $as.filter(':not(.bold)');
    var standby = $as.filter('.bold');

    current.addClass('bold');
    standby.removeClass('bold');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gW4dS/)

It can be written as

```
var $as = $('.filter a');
$('.filter').on('click', 'a:not(.bold)', function () {
    $as.toggleClass('bold');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hrn9V/)

Comment: +1 on the second solution, the first one is pointless and too much code.

Comment: @Phil that was to correct the OP's code.... and was the first solution before I cleaned it up.... so kept it there

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.filter').on('click','a:not(.bold)',function(){
  $(this).siblings().add(this).toggleClass('bold');
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
<div class="filter">
  <input type="radio" name="url" id="url1"><label for="url1">url1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="url" id="url2"><label for="url2">url2</label>
</div>
```

```
.filter input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
.filter input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

[Example 1](http://jsbin.com/ajUvImu/1/edit)
[Example 2](http://jsbin.com/OnUTEjO/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "filter", change it in your code or the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filtrer').on('click',' a:not(.bold)', function(){    
    $('.filtrer a.bold').removeClass('bold');;
    $(this).addClass('bold');    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
$('.filter a').click(function() {
    $('.filter a').removeClass('bold');
    $(this).addClass('bold');
});
```

?